# Can't open mapped file from address

Tags: c++, mapped-memory

I can't open mapped memory. When I use OpenFileMappingA() it returns NULL and GetLastError() returns 161 (ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME). I use the following code:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = { 0 };
VirtualQuery(image->raw_data, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));

if (mbi.Protect & PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
    ZeroMemory(image->raw_data, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) +  sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)  + sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)* nt_header->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
else if (mbi.Type & MEM_MAPPED)
{
    char buffer[500];
    size_t count = GetMappedFileNameA(GetCurrentProcess(), image->raw_data, buffer, sizeof(buffer));    
    HANDLE hMap = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, false, buffer);
    std::cout << hMap << std::endl; //0x00000000 
    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl; //161
}
```

Comment: You are not doing any error handling on GetMappedFileNameA, and what makes you think a memory mapping is using a file path as its name to begin with? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want edit memory at this region,but it's MEM_MAPPED region and I want to open mapped file at this location for changing page protection

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what MEM_MAPPED refers to. The memory being queried has already been mapped into memory, so just access the mapped data directly as needed, no need to open a new handle to the mapping object. Besides, you can't change the protection on the existing mapping anyway. The protection is set when the mapping object is first created and mapped into memory. Opening a new handle to the mapping object won't let you change its protection. So again, what are you REALLY trying to accomplish? This sounds like a possible XY problem.

Comment: I want to edit memory at this location,but it's have PAGE_READONLY protection

Comment: you can't use OpenFileMapping() to change the protection of an existing mapping object. Did you try VirtualProtect/Ex() instead? If that doesn't work, you are SOL

Comment: VirtualProtect I tried it's doesn't work.VirtualProtect call VirtualProtectEx so try VirtualProtectEx have no sence

Comment: I can use MapViewOfFile but i need HANDLE of file which i can't get

Answer (score 0):

"I want to edit memory at this location, but it's have PAGE_READONLY protection"

OpenFileMappingA doesn't have anything to do with protection.

You need to use [VirtualProtect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect) to change the protection of that memory region to [PAGE_READWRITE (0x04)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants)

```cpp
DWORD  curProtection = 0;
VirtualProtect(addr, len, PAGE_READWRITE, &curProtection);

//change the memory

//then restore old protection
VirtualProtect(toHook, len, curProtection, &curProtection);
```